# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when enumerating Active Directory groups

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

When enumerating a users Active Directory groups I'm getting the following error

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Here's my code:

```
internal static void admincheck(string username)
        {
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "EDIT");
            using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username))
            {
                System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groupList = user.GetGroups();
                foreach (GroupPrincipal @group in groupList)
                {
                    if (@group.Name == "students") { System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("no_access.aspx"); }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any ideas?  Thanks

Full stack trace:

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) at System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNLinkedAttrSet.MoveNextMemberSearcher() at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNLinkedAttrSet.MoveNext() at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.FindResultEnumerator`1.MoveNext() at TechnicalToolkit.toolkit.admincheck(String username) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: Which line threw the exception? (If you didn't have your if statement's body on one line, that would help.) Please show the full stack trace.

Comment: throws the exception at foreach (GroupPrincipal @group in groupList)

Comment: @AdamWinsper And what are the contets of groupList?

Comment: I've discovered what this was - the user didn't have access to read two of the groups that it was a member of in Active Directory.

i.e. user is a member of around 20 groups - groupList reached a group that the user account didn't have access to manage and threw this error.

I would've expected an Access Denied error myself!  Thanks

Comment: I discovered groups in an unknown state which caused this error.  Very weird - but if the user had such groups in their MemberOf attribute, a foreach or converting ToList would throw an exception